# how to send extras to an activity with Intents?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a BroadcastReceiver that listens for incoming sms messages. While a new sms arrives, it displays a notification that user can click on it and open the app. I want to pass the message text to my activity.

Inside my receiver:

```
Notification notifacation = new Notification();
notifacation.icon = icon;
notifacation.tickerText = tickerText;
notifacation.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("SMS_PARAMETERS", smsParameters);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra("SMS_PARAMETERS", bundle);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,   notificationIntent, 0);
notifacation.setLatestEventInfo(context, tickerText, message, contentIntent);
notificationManager.notify(1, notifacation);
```

Inside my activity:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    if( bundle != null) {
        String smsParameters = bundle.getString("SMS_PARAMETERS");
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "SMS_PARAMETERS: " + smsParameters);
        Toast.makeText(this, smsParameters, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }       
super.onResume();
}
```

The problem is that bundle is always null.

Any idea?

Comment: I think a lot of this is vastly wrong. You should not get the bundle in onResume(), notificationmanager handles notifications WITHOUT changing the Bundle or setLatestEventInfo. Your code never shows you actually passing the bundle to the intent? I'll answer your question but i'm not sure you're asking the right thing. To pass to an intent: Intent i = new Intent(MYCLASS.class); i.putExtra("KEY", 1); startActivity(i); then retrieve the extra in MYCLASS.class's onCreate like, this.getIntent().getExtras().getInt("KEY");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer:
I should add this line before startActivity(...)

```
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't see where you are adding the bundle to the intent. you need to do something like this:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("SMS_PARAMETERS", smsParameters);


Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, CarMapActivity.class);
notificationIntent.putExtras(bundle);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,   notificationIntent, 0);
notifacation.setLatestEventInfo(context, tickerText, message, contentIntent);
notificationManager.notify(1, notifacation);
```

Comment: There is no method putExtras(Bundle b) in Intent class (I am using android 2.1 API level 7). I changed the code like this: i.putExtras("SMS_PARAMETERS", smsParameters), but I still get null inside Activity.

Comment: try fixing your imports and rebuilding. I use that exact method `.putExtras(bundle);` multiple times in my code. Here is the doc for it: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtras(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: for some reason I can't post the correct link above. please add a ) to the end of the link and it will take you to the correct section of the page

Comment: I changed the code like this: intent.putExtra("key", bundle) but I get null. I read something that the Activity will reuse its initial bundle.